Hörmander: Analyticity and wave front sets of parameter integral in existence proof for parametrix for real principal type operators
I'm trying to understand the proof in Hörmanders Analysis of Differential Operators Vol 1 for Theorem 8.3.7. (Existence of parametrix for real principal type differential operators) (1) Citation of Hörmander (2) My understanding (3) My Questions
(1) Here one encounters the following elaboration by Hörmander:
*"
We set
$$
v(\xi)=P_m^{\prime}(\xi)|\xi|^{1-m}
$$
[P_m is principal symbol for differential operator of real principal type, P_m' Gradient]
[…]
Let $\Gamma$ be the chain
$$
\mathbb{R}^n \ni \xi \rightarrow \xi+i t v(\xi), \quad|\xi| \geqq C_3,
$$
[…]
To complete the proof we must show that $\left(x_0, \xi_0\right) \notin W F\left(E_{-}\right)$ $x_0 \notin \mathbb{R} \_P_m^{\prime}\left(\xi_0\right)$. This condition means precisely that we can find $V \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|V|=1$ and
$$
\left\langle x_0, V\right\rangle>0,\left\langle P_m^{\prime}\left(\xi_0\right), V\right\rangle>0 .
$$
Choosing a conic neighborhood $W$ of $\xi_0$ such that for some $c>0$
$$
\left\langle P_m^{\prime}(\xi), V\right\rangle>c|\xi|^{m-1}, \quad \xi \in W,
$$
we obtain from (8.3.10) when $\xi \in W$
[…]
$$
\begin{gathered}
\operatorname{Im} P(\xi+i t v(\xi)+i s V) \geqq C_1(1+|\xi|)^{m-1}, \\
\xi \in W, \quad 0 \leqq s \leqq|\xi|, \quad|\xi| \geqq C_3^{\prime} .
\end{gathered}
$$
Choose $\chi \in C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^n \backslash 0\right)$ homogeneous of degree 0 with support in $W$
so
that $0 \leqq \chi \leqq 1$, and $\chi=1$ in a conic neighborhood $W_0$ of $\xi_0$. If $\langle x, V\rangle>0$, which is true in a neighborhood of $x_0$, we obtain using Stokes' formula
$(8.3 .13)^{\prime}$
$$
E_{-}(x)=(2 \pi)^{-n} \int_{\Gamma^{\prime} \cup \Gamma_0^{\prime}} e^{i\langle x, \zeta\rangle} / P(\zeta) d \zeta_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge d \zeta_n
$$
where $\Gamma^{\prime}$ is the chain
$$
\mathbb{R}^n \ni \xi \rightarrow \xi+i t v(\xi)+i|\xi| \chi(\xi) V, \quad|\xi| \geqq C_3^{\prime},
$$
and $\Gamma_0^{\prime}$ is the union of the part of $\Gamma$ where $C_3<|\xi|<C_3^{\prime}$ with the chain
$$
\left\{(\xi, s) ;|\xi|=C_3^{\prime}, 0<s<C_3^{\prime}\right\} \rightarrow \xi+i t v(\xi)+i s \chi(\xi) V
$$
with suitable orientations. The contribution to (8.3.13)' when $\zeta \in \Gamma_0^{\prime}$ or $\operatorname{Re} \zeta \in W_0$ is an analytic function of $x$ when $\langle x, V\rangle>0$."*
(2) I'm trying to understand the last sentence:
(In my notation: $\Gamma_{out}:=\Gamma'$ $\Gamma_{in}:=\Gamma'_0$ $\Gamma_{out}|_{W_0}:=\{\zeta \in \Gamma_{out}; \Re(\zeta)\in W_0\}$, $\Gamma_in|_{/W_0}:=\{\zeta \in \Gamma_{out}; \Re(\zeta)\notin W_0\}$)
\begin{align*}
E_-(x) &=(2\pi)^{-n}\int\limits_{\Gamma_{\operatorname{out}}\cup\Gamma_{\operatorname{in}}}\frac{e^{i\langle x,\zeta\rangle}}{P(\zeta)}d\zeta\\
&= (2\pi)^{-n}\left(\ \int\limits_{\Gamma_{\operatorname{in}}\cup\Gamma_{\operatorname{out}}|_{W_0}} \frac{e^{i\langle x,\zeta\rangle}}{P(\zeta)}d\zeta + \int\limits_{\Gamma_{\operatorname{out}}|_{/ W_0}} \frac{e^{i\langle x,\zeta\rangle}}{P(\zeta)}d\zeta\right)\\
\end{align*}
So we get the wave front set inclusion
$$\WF(E_-)\overset{x\in U(x_0)}{\subseteq}  \WF\left(\ \int\limits_{\Gamma_{\operatorname{in}}\cup\Gamma_{\operatorname{out}}|_{W_0}} e^{i\langle x,\zeta\rangle}/P(\zeta)d\zeta \right)\bigcup\  \WF\left(\ \int\limits_{\Gamma_{\operatorname{out}}|_{/ W_0}} e^{i\langle x,\zeta\rangle}/P(\zeta)d\zeta \right)$$
Following here \textbf{Hörmander} in his proof, he claims that the first parameter integral  is in fact analytic in the parameter $x$, so the wave front set of the first integral representation is empty for $x\in U(x_0)$.
So analysing $\WF(E_-)$ with the chosen integral representation for $x\in U(x_0)$ reduces to analysing the wave front set of the second parameter integral for $x\in U(x_0)$
$$\WF(E_-)=\WF\left(\ \int\limits_{\Gamma_{\operatorname{out}}|_{/ W_0}} e^{i\langle x,\zeta\rangle}/P(\zeta)d\zeta \right)$$
(3) My Question:
a) Is this understanding on track
b) Why is the first parameter integral real analytic in x, but not the second one (which would make the proof kind of trivial)
